# Wordpress Multisite Subdomain Adding

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, cpanel, whm

I have a multisite network setup in wordpress where main domain is for example domain.com , Now I want to add a subdomain of another domain(blog.anotherdomain.com) to the multisite network with main domain. Now the problem is my anotherdomain.com is already added in WHM and have a different wordpress site. Now, if I want to add blog.anotherdomain.com to the multisite wordpress setup, I need to add it as addon domain to domain.com. But as the anotherdomain.com is already registered with another user on whm/cpanel .. I am not able to add the addon domain and it's giving an error .. Please help .. I hope I am clear

Error ->  The domain “blog.anotherdomain.com” may not be created by “someaccountusername” because “anotherdomain.com” is already owned by another user.

Comment: what error is actually throwing? could you please reformat the question as well to make it more clear?

Comment: you cannot use the anotherdomain.com subdomain on another different host for this you have to add dns A record or cname record for blog.anotherdomain.com then you can add this in addon domain

Comment: Error ->  The domain “blog.anotherdomain.com” may not be created by “someaccountusername” because “anotherdomain.com” is already owned by another user.

Answer (score 0):

Point by adding a CNAME to the domain or subdomain.

Comment: What cname to use and where to point.. I have already added an A record to the main server IP for the subdomain on domain registrar

Comment: In DNS:
CNAME blog.anotherdomain.com  is an alias of   domain.com.

Comment: I added and now when I access blog.anotherdomain.com it's displays a different domain in my whm.. I want to access a newsite hosted under wordpress multisite of domain.com  when I visit  blog.anotherdomain.com